# Porque minha Div, criada em JS, não aparece?

Tags: javascript, funções, javascript-eventos, create, elementos

Meu objetivo é criar um quadrado vermelho, diferente, toda vez que a pessoa clicar no botão. só que quando a pessoa clica no botão não acontece nada de esperado. mas dá pra saber que o **addEventListener** está funcionando, pois se criar um **alert** dentro dele, quando clicar no botão o **alert** aparece.
Obrigado ;)

segue meu código:

```js
var button = document.createElement('input') //cria um input
button.setAttribute('value', 'ok') //coloca seu valor como ok, ou seja, o texto do input será 'ok'
button.setAttribute('type', 'button') // muda o tipo do input para um botão (button)
document.querySelector('div#button').appendChild(button) //adiciona o botão como filho da div

button.addEventListener('click', function createSquare(){ //Cria uma função que quando o botão for clicado será executada

    var square = document.createElement('div') //cria uma div
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(square) //adiciona a div como filha do body
    square.style.width  = 100; //muda a largura pra 100px
    square.style.height = 100; //muda a altura para 100px
    square.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //muda a cor de fundo para vermelho
})
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está colocando os valores de `width` e `height` de forma errada. As divs estão até sendo criadas, mas elas não aparecem porque não tem nada nelas e os valores das propriedades citadas acima estão errados.

As propriedades `width` e `height` precisam, além de um valor numérico, uma unidade (`px`, `em`, `rem`, `%` etc.), portanto, deveria ser uma string, e você está colocando apenas um valor numérico `100`:

```
square.style.width  = 100; //muda a largura pra 100px
square.style.height = 100; //muda a altura para 100px
```

O correto seria:

```
square.style.width  = '100px'; //muda a largura pra 100px
square.style.height = '100px'; //muda a altura para 100px
```

Veja:

```js
var button = document.createElement('input') //cria um input
button.setAttribute('value', 'ok') //coloca seu valor como ok, ou seja, o texto do input será 'ok'
button.setAttribute('type', 'button') // muda o tipo do input para um botão (button)
document.querySelector('div#button').appendChild(button) //adiciona o botão como filho da div

button.addEventListener('click', function createSquare(){ //Cria uma função que quando o botão for clicado será executada

   var square = document.createElement('div') //cria uma div
   document.querySelector('body').appendChild(square) //adiciona a div como filha do body
   square.style.width  = '100px'; //muda a largura pra 100px
   square.style.height = '100px'; //muda a altura para 100px
   square.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //muda a cor de fundo para vermelho
}
)
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: Cara, vlw. Mas mesmo mudando isso, quando clico no botão não acontece o que eu esperaria

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo funcionando na resposta. Veja que funciona normalmente.

Comment: Ah, muito obrigado msm. Eu tinha esquecido de colocar 'px' no final. Deus te abençoe

Comment: Blz. Não deixe de marcar ✔ na resposta. Abs!